# Placing String from strings.xml in the Toast Message

Tags: java, android, xml, string, toast

I'm currently finishing my game app for android, but I have encountered one problem that keeps crashing my app.

I was trying to **place the text from strings.xml inside the toast message** and my code looks like this:

```
    // THIS IS THE PART THAT DOES NOT WORK:
    int stringrank = getResources().getIdentifier("rank"+points, "string", this.getPackageName());
    rank = getString(stringrank);
    // I want to get different rank String depending on the collected points, 
    // so it would be rank1, rank2, rank3 and so on - thats why "rank"+points.
    // It worked for me in the different parts of the code, but when I want to
    // use it in the Toast Message it does not.


    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.done_toast, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.done_toast));
    TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
    // APP CRASHES when I use "rank" String here, if I place other text it works just fine.
    text.setText(rank);

    final Toast donetoast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
    donetoast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 35);
    donetoast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    donetoast.setView(layout);
    // Rest of the Toast Message code is below, not important.
    (...)
```

When I place the normal text in the Toast Message (does not matter whether in Java or in the done_toast.xml) it works perfectly, but if I want to **call the String from strings.xml the app crashes.**

*Thank you for your help in advance!*

Comment: Show us the logcat output of the crash so we can know what the exception is and what line of code it happened on.

Comment: Ok, I double checked the log, it was totally stupid mistake and had nothing to do with the Java Code. "rank" String in strings.xml had had its font size in "sp" like: 
<string name="rank1"><font size='16sp'><b>ROOKIE</b></font></string> 
While it should be plain '16'. Corrected it and it works well. I'm sorry for bothering you guys, cheers for help!

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a Toast object like that. It must be done using **Toast.makeText()**.

Try this

```
final Toast donetoast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext());
donetoast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
donetoast.setView(layout);
```

Comment: It is a custom made toast for the game (graphics etc.) with separate .xml file associated with it. It works well (I have 4 different toast messages in the code already) it just crashes when I want to put String from strings.xml file in it. If I write it in the toast message, or I specify it in the toast.xml file it works just fine. Question was about the "rank" String.

Comment: Please put the logcat

Comment: Ok, I double checked the log, it was totally stupid mistake and had nothing to do with the Java Code. "rank" String in strings.xml had had its font size in "sp" like: 
<string name="rank1"><font size='16sp'><b>ROOKIE</b></font></string> 
While it should be plain '16'. Corrected it and it works well. I'm sorry for bothering you mate, cheers for help!

Comment: Not a problem at all